# How can I check if the system time of the DB server is correct?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jboss

I have got a bug case from the service desk, which was a result of different system times on the application server (JBoss) and DB(Oracle) server. As a result, timeouts lied.
It doesn't happen often, but for the future, it will be better if the app server could raise alarm about the bad time on the DB server before it results in some deeper problems.

Of course, I can simply read

```
Select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

, and compare it against the local time. But it is probable that the time of sending the query and getting its result will get some noticeable time and I will recognize good time as bad one or vice versa.

I can also check the time from sending the query to the return of the result. But this way will work correctly in the case of the good net without lags. And if the time on the DB server fails, it is highly probable that the net around the DB server is not OK. The queues on the DB server can make the times of sending and receiving noticeably unequal.

What is the best way you know to check the time on the DB server?
Limitations: preciseness of 5 sec
false alarms <10%
To be optimized(minimized): lost alarms.

Maybe I am inventing the bicycle and JBoss and/or Oracle have some tool for that? (I could not find it)

Comment: Why don't you use a NTP server on the DB and the JBoss server to synchronize time?

Comment: 1. Most working people do only some small part of the great structure and often cannot even influence the outer structures. 2. Checking installations by hand is much less sure than checking by software. 3. The administration of the connection to the time server can be broken. 4. Heaps of things can be broken on the computer so that the time will be incorrect.

Comment: Why tag sql server?

Comment: I can't guarantee this will work, but your best hope for a "no lag time" solution would be to compare `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to `SYSTIMESTAMP` in Oracle. `SYSTIMESTAMP` is the time on the Oracle server and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the time on your app server. Something like `SELECT CASE WHEN SYSTIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END FROM DUAL`. If you can tolerate a difference of a one second then it becomes `SELECT CASE WHEN SYSTIMESTAMP BETWEEN CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '1' SECOND THEN 'Good' ELSE 'Bad' END FROM DUAL`

Comment: Current_timestamp returns timestamp in session time zone, not server's one

Comment: Ntp is the only solution for that. System clock can fall behind

Comment: @EdGibbs Excellent! That is what I need, I wanted to make check from the DB server side, too, and your receipt is just about that. Please make this an answer!

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I am not asking about how to keep up the time on the DB server. I am asking, how can app server notice that DB server time is not OK.

Comment: In short, it can't. Without ntp. And as I wrote above Current_timestamp is just systimestamp in session time zone. And Ntp is not just time sync it also shows lag and time drift.

Comment: If webapp session uses the same timezone, Current_timestamp is always equal to systimestamp. Change session timezone and you will see difference in time zones

Comment: From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions037.htm CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the current date and time in the session time zone, in a value of datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE. The time zone offset reflects the current local time of the SQL session.

Answer (score 1):

Have a program running on the app server get the current time there, then query the database time (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and the app server gets the current time there after the query returns.

Confirm that the DB time is between the two times on the App Server (with any tolerance you need). You can include a separate check on how long it took to get the response from the DB but it should be trivial.

If the environment is some form of VM, issues are most likely to arise when the VM is started or resumed from a pause. There might be situations where a clock is running fast or slow so recording the times would allow you to look for trends in either direction and allow you to take preemptive action.